# How can I achieve the piece by piece effect without Muse?

Tags: parallax, muse

I'm trying to do what [this website](http://www.scrolleffects.com/the-piece-by-piece-effect.html) does with the piece by piece effect. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I can use Muse with code, or if it has to be graphics based. I would rather use a technique that is only code, without any special tools.

I found [WOW.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/), but I'm not sure if it can achieve the same effect.

Thanks.

Comment: As a personal opinion, that's just about the worst possible user experience you can offer on your site.

Comment: This is for an aesthetics competition. When used right, this technique can achieve a very powerful effect.